# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getId' of undefined

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have written this script to my spreadsheet which is connected to a google form too, and connected dropdown function to a button on spreadsheet so as be easier to run the script. first it worked well but now it is saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getId' of undefined (line 34, file "Code")`(this line was 34 -->`var itemID = item.getId();`)
 I do not understand what is going wrong in this script.
how can I fix this? 
Thank you for your help in advance!!!

````
var ssID = "1Z7uUBnzS5zKnxGswKKNAgn2XbRunqIzQZMATDl7skoE";
var formID = "1LxORhL2WgU6teJ11ax7_HsFxhbpXbjtFXiuPH5qfEfA";

var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("Questions#1");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function dropdown() {
var labels = wsData.getRange(1, 1, 1, wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  labels.forEach(function(label,i){
    var options = wsData
                  .getRange(2, i+1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1)
                  .getValues()
                  .map(function(o){ return o[0] })
                  .filter(function(o){ return o !== "" });

    updateDropdownUsingTitle(label,options);
  });

}  


function updateDropdownUsingTitle(title,values) {
   var items = form.getItems();
   var titles = items.map(function(item){
   return item.getTitle();
});

   var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
   var item = items[pos];
   var itemID = item.getId(pos);

  updateDropdown(itemID,values); 
}


function updateDropdown(id,values) {
  var item = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
}```
````

Comment: Please add sample data of Questions#1 and Questions#2 and a link to a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to to view only in order to be able to reproduce the error message that you are getting. By the way, this is your third question, how come that are still having 1 rep. If the answers that you got are good, please accept them. Ref. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Question in the form **Mas'ul xodim** . Answers:
Bobur CEO 
aroon
aroonbank
Nozima
Asilbek
Rahmatjon
Hamzat
Farzona

Comment: [the link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vfHoNzm0ngApBNgX9VzWY8-tuRgDME2Xcm8nODhIEDk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: [the link to the form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScj0XvjQGPC9JJloS4SStH6bdyCmPScECwp0mbPzVkxTmI9Tw/viewform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
var labels = wsData.getRange(1, 1, 1, wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
```

As it's returning `Bobur CEO` instead of the expected values.

Replace the above line by

```
var labels = wsData.getRange(1, 1, 1, wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues().map(function(row){
  return row[0];
});
```

`.map(function(row){return row[0];})` will flatten the result of `.getValues()`.

Comment: As you can see there several columns with questions,  and  I wanted this script to apply all changes to the form question (all in dropdown format) when I add new answers to the existing questions and/or add new questions next to existing ones. 
#1 the problem after replacing the line You said the changes are being applied to only the first question. 
#2 2nd problem is that as you can see there is a ```RUN``` button on Questions#1 sheet. after making changes I use this button to run the script so as to apply changes. But the message ```Finished script``` appears whenever I click on it

Comment: then changes are not applied if I use this button. Please have a look on the [Questions#1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z7uUBnzS5zKnxGswKKNAgn2XbRunqIzQZMATDl7skoE/edit?usp=sharing). the first row of each column(each column is a different question) is a separate question under which there are the answers to it.

Comment: @AroonAdvisoryGroup I think that I correctly answered your question. If you have follow-up questions, please post a new question.

Comment: but when i run the other two function it is sating there are still errors in the line 31 and 38